# How to create a simple checkout flow for mobile app and update it in the mysql database?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html, hybrid-mobile-app

i am building an ecommerce app for my website. This is the first time i am developing an app. As of now i am making use of phone gap to do the work for me. But i am stuck at this particular place, i have made the cart and it is working fine and i have made the checkout form also separately. But i don't know how to pass the product information from the cart to the checkout flow and then update it in the database. As of now i am sending the product parameters through the url but i know it is not safe. and i make use of

```
 location.search.string(1)
```

to get all product parameter from the cart and then attach these to the form data and send it to the php file and from there i add it to the database. Again in the database i am having another problem. I am maintaining two different table, one for the orde information and the other for products. But here the problem is i don't know how to link the two table i.e when a new order is created an order id is assigned to it, now i don't know how to get that order id and use that order id to update the product information in product table. So can some one help me out with these two problems.

I am using jquery and html to create the app and php and mysql for the server side.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add some of your done work here for more understanding ? AFAIK you requirement, you can get order id by last inserted id from selected table and update it. Or store temp order id first and use that.

Comment: @shivam i tried doing that before but what if there are 100's of transaction happening at the same time. In that getting the last order_id can be risky. So thats why i wanted some other way than last inserted

Comment: Did you try with temp. order id with last id ? that will be unique, check id with temp order id

Comment: @shivam can you elaborate on that a bit.

Comment: You have to store product id, and its detail i.e. qty in order table. So its easy for update product data. for example your order table contain product id 5 with qty 3 then update your product table where id = 5 with qty by -3

Comment: @shivam i think using Last_insert_id() is only better. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80245/discussion-between-shivam-pandya-and-susan-williams).